# How do I use a callback in a for loop? - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I've got a problem with getting data from a callback inside a for loop

```
        getClipsFromFollowers: function (gameList, streamerList, callback) {
            var allClips = []
            console.log("gamelist in getclips", gameList);

            for (game of gameList) {
                console.log("game in getclips", game);
                clipsGameManager.getListByName(game, function (error, list) {
                    if (list == []) {
                        twitchManager.getTopClipsFromGame(game, function (clips) {
                            clipsGameManager.createGameClips(game, clips, function (error, status) {
                                if (error != null) {
                                    console.log(error)
                                } else {
                                    if(list != null){
                                        console.log("listfromGame getclips", list)
                                        allClips = allClips.concat(list)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            allClips = allClips.concat(clips)
                            console.log(clips);
                        })
                    } 
                })
            }
            console.log("allclips in getclips", allClips);
            callback(null, allClips)
        }
```

The logs looks like this:

```
gamelist in getclips [ 'Overwatch' ]
game in getclips Overwatch
allclips in getclips []
[]
```

So my question is what can I do to make this work? I've tried to use await() with no success.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You code passes `name` to `getTopClipsFromGame()` but `name` does not appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Also `if (list == [])` will **never** succeed; no array is `==` to any other array.